# C++: Implicit assignment for Objects

Tags: c++, object, variable-assignment, implicit

I have been looking for quite some time for my question, but I haven't found any satisfying answer yet.
The question is fairly easy: What should I put between the brackets when I use Implicit Assignment for an Object.

I was always used to seeing something like this: The assign an int, you give it an int-value

```
class Point2D
{
private:
    int m_nX;
    int m_nY;

public:    
    // A specific constructor
    Point2D(int nX, int nY)
        : m_nX(nX), m_nY(nY) // So the int m_nX gets the int-value nX
    {
    }
}
```

---

But recently I found a tutorial where PARAMETERS were given to an object. (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/)

```
class PersonalComputer
{
private:
   CPU m_cCPU;
   Motherboard m_cMotherboard;
   RAM m_cRAM;

public:
   PersonalComputer::PersonalComputer(int nCPUSpeed, char *strMotherboardModel, int nRAMSize)
       : m_cCPU(nCPUSpeed), m_cMotherboard(strMotherboardModel), m_cRAM(nRAMSize)
       // So the m_cCPU-object is given a parameter nCPUSpeed, and not another m_cCPU-object
   {
   }
};
```

So my question is: How does Implicit Assignment work for objects? And how can I assign an Object with an Object itself (e.g. give an m_cCPU2-object to the m_cCPU-object).

Thanks

Comment: First you have to realize there is no assignment going on in your code. Search for "converting constructors".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "implicit assignment", but I have a feeling you're looking to understand how *copy construction* works. In short, there's a special copy constructor that copies one object's values to its own values -- and the compiler generates a default copy constructor when you don't provide your own.

Comment: This additional `PersonalComputer::` in the constructor declaration is redundant.

Comment: An instance of a class can take a different type as an argument to its constructor. As juanchopanza put it, it is called a *converting constructor*. To *initialize* an object with an object of the same type is to call the [*copy-constructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign an initialize an object with another object in the initializer list you want to define a *copy constructor*

```
class CPU
{
    CPU(const CPU& other)
      : someSpeedVariable(other.someSpeedVariable) // Eg.
    {}
}
```

Then you can do this in other classes.

```
class PC
{
    PC(const CPU& cpu)
      :m_cpu(cpu)
    {}
    CPU m_cpu;
}
```

I think this is what you're asking?

Comment: No, they are asking how come a `CPU` can be initialized from an `int`.

Comment: I'm answering: _"And how can I assign an Object with an Object itself (e.g. give an m_cCPU2-object to the m_cCPU-object)."_ Which sounds like assignment operator or copy constructor work to me.

Comment: You're right, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Well, you might not know it, but you solved my question :), so thanks a lot man. I thought it was called Implicit Assignment because they call it that way on the CPP website (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/)

Answer (score 1):

This is called *initialization* (not "implicit assignment").

For a primitive type it means that object is given that initial value

```
int nX(5);
```

For a class type it means to call the class's constructor with those arguments:

```
Motherboard m("ABCDE");
```